# Format decimal before insert in MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I imported information from txt files. I have 3 files, and one field from this file is a price with different format.

The format on column is DECIMAL(12,5)

```
file 1 -> $price_1 = 000000000000024.99

file 2 -> $price_2 = 25476,99

file 3 -> $price_3 = 3,768.44
```

Before inserting in mySQL table I using folowing script:

**For file 1**

```
$price = (real)number_format($price_1 , 2, '.', '');
```

**For file 2**

```
$price = (real)str_replace(",", ".", $price_2);
```

**For file 3**

```
$price = (real)str_replace(",", "", price_3);
```

I do't know if this format is correct before I insert a record in the table?
If there is any other solution I'll be very grateful. 
I apologize for my English. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are absolutely, completely sure that the numbers are in those formats, you can do that, yes. But if I'm guessing correctly, price_2 could also look like `12.345.678,90` and then you would be in trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use printf or sprintf php functions to get numbers in proper format.